Корректное отображение документации в quick documentation intellij idea
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать корректное отображение docstring документации в quick documentation intellij idea?
Дело в том, что я вижу в "первом блоке" весь текст своего описания, причём текст свален в одну кучу. Далее идёт отдельно описание параметров и того, что возвращает функция.
Хотелось бы в первом блоке видеть только короткий текст.
Пример функции и описания:
def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta = None):
    """
    <p>Создает JWT токен с ID пользователя и ролью.</p>
    :param data: Данные для токена (должны содержать 'user_id' и 'role')
    :param expires_delta: Время жизни токена (если не указано, используется значение по умолчанию)
    :return: JWT токен
    """

Скрин из быстрой документации:

